# Sqlite3 php parse error selecting date range

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to change a selection to only include the last so many days of data in my sqlite database but i am getting parse error and just don't know what i am doing wrong.

here is the section of code, the original command $results = has been commented out the second one causes errors.

```
    $db = new SQLite3($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/yieldbuddy/www/sql/yieldbuddy.sqlite3');
    $db->busyTimeout(2000);
    #$results = $db->query('SELECT *    FROM Sensors_Log');
    $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Sensors_Log WHERE Time >=  DateTime('now','-14 days')');
    $rownum=0;

    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

    $Time_array[$rownum] = $row[0];
    $pH1_array[$rownum] = $row[1];
```

here is the error i keep getting when trying to view the page

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'now' (T_STRING) in /var/www/yieldbuddy/www/graphs_2.php on line 128
```

the first column in the table sensors_log is called time and is basically a datetime formatted timestamp the column is called Time in the database. I am passing the data to a google visulizaiton but if i select all records its too much data and the page crashes. I am trying to limit the dataset passed to google.

What am i doing wrong it says syntax error but i cannot figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) says:

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\).

So:

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM Sensors_Log WHERE Time >= DateTime(\'now\',\'-14 days\')');
```